# Crontab cant dump the base

Tags: bash, shell, cron

My crontabfile have a line

```
* * * * * root /home/pk1/Templates/dump.sh
```

my dump.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=toor mba_new | gzip > /home/pk1/Templates/`date +"webt-backup_%m-%d-%y"`.gz
```

If i write in bash sh dump.sh - everything work, but cronjob not work. Why?

Comment: There are two different forms of crontab file. The normal kind, installed using the `crontab` command, does not specify a user name; the job is executed by the account that ran the `crontab` command. In a system crontab file, such as `/etc/crontab`, the account name is given after the 5 time/date fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab line is wrong, the root has nothing to do here.
It should be like that:

```
* * * * * /home/pk1/Templates/dump.sh
```

if you are trying to run this command as root, then you have to use `sudo`, or install this cron line inside the crontab of the `root` user (which is not recommended, you should never run anything on a regular basis as root).

Answer (score 0):

in crontab wrote `sh /home/pk1/Templates/dump.sh` and everthing ok

Comment: Do you mean you replaced `root` by `sh`?

Comment: This should probably be added to the question.